# What does some reports have the same safetyreportid?

Tags: openfda

I thought that safetyreportid is the unique identity of a report, but I found that some safetyreportid like "5390497-5" has two or three reports in openFDA when I search by API:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=safetyreportid:%225390497-5%22&limit=99

Could I ask why there are multiple reports with the same safetyreportid in openFDA?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated on the [FDA FAERS page](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/questions-and-answers-fdas-adverse-event-reporting-system-faers/fda-adverse-event-reporting-system-faers-public-dashboard):

> Duplicate and incomplete reports are in the system: There are many instances of duplicative reports and some reports do not contain all the necessary information.

This is one of those cases.

Comment: Sorry does that mean the cases in FDA FAERS are the same as the cases in openFDA API? But why the number of cases in FAERS is different from openFDA? Like for 2020q1, there are 460,327 cases in FDA FAERS but 457,999 cases in openFDA (https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receiptdate:[20200101+TO+20200331])