# Does OpenFDA have duplicate reports?

Tags: openfda

In an answer of this specific question on stack exchange:
[What does some reports have the same safetyreportid?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17710/what-does-some-reports-have-the-same-safetyreportid)
It is stated that openfda has duplicates:
'Duplicate and incomplete reports are in the system: There are many instances of duplicative reports and some reports do not contain all the necessary information'

However, checking openfda site for the  duplicate field description:

[image: Screenshot of Searching OpenFDA for "duplicate"]

The site states that openFDA shows only the most recent version (meaning there is no duplicates on the openFDA)

I am a bit confused whether the openFDA API data provides duplicates or not.
I would love to hear more clarification about this matter.

Answer (score 0):

"Opening data means cleaning data" from "https://www.techrepublic.com/article/openfda-launches-open-data-platform-for-consumer-protection/".
"We had removed duplicate records when we did the harmonization process. There are now 15 identifiers mapped to 85% of the adverse events data." said by Herron from FDA